# Is $S:= \{x\cos\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right): x\in [-9,2]\}$ bounded above?

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Verify whether the set $S:= \{x\cos\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right): x\in [-9,2]\}$ is bounded above.

I'm not sure what is the correct approach, I started, assuming there exists an upper bound $u$ and then I used the definition to get $x\cos\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right) \leq u \hspace{10pt}\forall x\in [-9,2]$.

Then I realised that $0\in [-9,2]$ but $f(0)$ is undefined, where $f(x)= x\cos\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right)$.
This it seems that $S$ can't be bounded above, but this can't be rigorous proof.

Comment: $S$ is not properly defined since $x=0$ creates a problem.  If you define the expression to be $0$ when $x=0$ then $9$ is an  upper bound .

Comment: 1. for $x=0$ the expression $x\cos\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right)$ is not defined. 2. if $x \in [-9,2] $ and $x \ne 0$, then $|x\cos\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right)| \le |x| \le 3..$

Comment: If you'll don't mind, can you provide me with the whole rigorous proof, that I have to write it out.

Comment: @Fred I think you missed the $-9$. $3$ is not an upper bound.

Comment: oops, you are right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In its present form, the question does not make sense - for $x\cos\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right)$ is not defined at $x = 0$. One option is to define $x\cos\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right) = 0$ at $x = 0$, and another is to simply forget about $x = 0$. I have discussed the second one below.

---

Let's talk about $S = \left\{x\cos\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right) : x\in [-9,0) \cup (0,2]\right\}$ because $x\cos\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right)$ is not defined at $x = 0$.
Note that $$\left|x\cos\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right)\right| \le |x|$$ when $x \ne 0$, and for $x\in [-9,0) \cup (0,2]$ we have $|x| \le 9$. Hence, $9$ is an upper bound for $S$. $S$ is bounded above.